# If I have a production function f where the marginal product of all the input is constant, can f exhibit decreasing returns to scale?

Tags: microeconomics, production-function

Marginal product of input xi=
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f }{\partial x _{i}} 
\end{equation}

Decreasing return to scale:
f(tx,ty) < t f(x,y) for t>1

Answer (score 2):

Yes:
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=-x_1x_2
$$
has constant marginal return in both inputs and decreasing return to scale by your definition.

---

EDIT: Answer above assumes OP meant "constant" as constant w.r.t. the input whose marginal product we are talking about. For totally constant, see the the [answer to the duplicate question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39860/returns-to-scale-microeconomics).

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks! :)